# Creating a function to extract n groups from a dataset

Tags: r

I am searching for a way to extract the first n groups of rows from a dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(PersonID= sample(1:10, 25,replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(25))
```

If I want to extract the first 4 groups, ie. rows with PersonID=3,4,6,10

```
     PersonID      value
  1         3 -0.2894616
  2         4 -0.2992151
  3         6 -0.4115108
  4        10  0.2522234
  5         3 -0.8919211
  ----------------------
```

Comment: and what if there are fewer than `n` groups in the dataset?

Comment: @Spacedman. In that case, should not return anything.

Comment: A function has to return something - NA? NULL? data frame with zero rows? - unless it stops and raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

I used unique:

```
data[data$PersonID %in% unique(data$PersonID)[1:4],]

   PersonID      value
1         3 -0.2894616
2         4 -0.2992151
3         6 -0.4115108
4        10  0.2522234
5         3 -0.8919211
7        10 -1.2375384
11        3  0.8041895
14        4  1.0857694
18       10 -0.2357066
19        4 -0.5428883
21       10 -0.6494716
22        3  0.7267507
25        3 -0.4295131
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following simple code:

```
xx =c(3,4,6,10 )

data[data$PersonID %in% xx,]
   PersonID      value
1         3 -0.2894616
2         4 -0.2992151
3         6 -0.4115108
4        10  0.2522234
5         3 -0.8919211
7        10 -1.2375384
11        3  0.8041895
14        4  1.0857694
18       10 -0.2357066
19        4 -0.5428883
21       10 -0.6494716
22        3  0.7267507
25        3 -0.4295131
```